# get hostname of remote clients accessing my website using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dns

I have a Vb.net based website which is a pretty old one can't upgrade it.
I need the hostname of the clients visiting the website.

On page load of the login page I am calling using this which gets me the client's hostname who's accessing the website.

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")).HostName
```

I am logging the details into my Database which is similar to the below

```
172.xx.xx.xx    ltp-017  RUPESH
```

I have no problem catching the IP address and hostname of devices accessing my website from home network but when a device(including mobile devices) is accessing from outside my home network the above code does not catch the hostname.

Is there any other option or programming language which I can use inside my VB.Net to achieve this?

Any ideas to get this work is much appreciated.
Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you shouldn't see the hostname either. I would be most concerned if websites I were accessing on the internet could "spy" of the names of the different devices I use to access the website. Asking for the hostname of the machine accessing the website if like asking for their local IP.

Comment: This website is an attendance punching website and it doesn't do anything more than that. Our HR team Just wants to monitor whether somebody else is not doing punching other than their own.

Comment: That would be better managed then by some good authentication processes; a username and password. Then you know who is using the website.

Comment: I understand your point but this is not something which is very sensitive information about a client, if I am not wrong windows server and other servers' do keep a log of client's IP addresses in the server which is visible to the admin.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.UserHostAddress` gives the IP of the connected remote client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?view=netframework-4.7.2